# Generic & Mapped Type Narrowing

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

```
type ModalProps = {
  login: LoginModalProps;
  signup: SignupModalProps;
};

interface ModalRootProps<K extends keyof ModalProps> {
  modalType: K;
  modalProps: ModalProps[K];
}

export function ModalRoot<ModalType extends keyof ModalProps>(props: ModalRootProps<ModalType>) {
  switch (props.modalType) {
    case 'login': {
      return <LoginModal {...props.modalProps}/>;
    }

    case 'signup': {
      return <SignupModal {...props.modalProps} />;
    }

    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

This code results in a

> TypeError on props.modalProps (LoginFormProps is not assignable to
>   SignupFormProps).

When `ModalType` is narrowed to `'login'` within the `switch` statement, I would expect `modalProps` to be typed as `ModalProps['switch']` (SignupFormProps) but it is still typed as `ModalProps[K]`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type guards like this usually work with discriminated unions. You can use `ModalProps` to create such a type and then the type guard will work as expected.

```
type ModalRootProps<T extends keyof ModalProps> =  T extends keyof ModalProps ? { modalProps: ModalProps[T], modalType: T}: never 

export function ModalRoot(props: ModalRootProps<keyof ModalProps>) {
    switch (props.modalType) {
        case 'login': {
            return <LoginModal { ...props.modalProps } />;
        }
        case 'signup': {
            return <SignupModal { ...props.modalProps } />;
        }

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Not sure why your original code does not work, type guards are usually pretty particular about narrowing types.

Comment: Thanks! It seems odd that you need to do the ternary check that `T extends keyof ModalProps`, I thought the generic would take care of that.

Comment: It does , I use conditional types because of the way they iterate over union types